# Populate array with items of another array in ascending order (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have an array of arrays of different lengths. So for instance in my test below I start with my `vidArray` containing 4 arrays (their length is respectively 16, 38, 49, 49).
I'd like to populate a `newArray` with the first value of each of the 4 arrays, then the second value of each, then the third and so on.

What I'm trying is:

```
      // populate newArray
      var newArray = []
      for(let i=0; i < vidArray.length; i++){
        let ar = vidArray[i]
        for(let j=i; j < (i+1); j++){
          newArray.push(ar[j])
        }
      }

      console.log("newArray "+newArray)
```

but it seems to wrongly take the [0] from the first array, the [1] from the second array, the [3] from the third array and so on

Comment: What will you do when there is no more items in first array, but exists in second? `null`/terminate?

Comment: Ideally i'd stop fetching that array's items

Comment: So you just want to go until the end of the shortest subarray has been reached?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can figure out the maximum length of the subarrays, then iterate over that length, pushing the corresponding values from each subarray into the new array as you go, skipping any that don't exist:

```js
const vidArray = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  [11, 12, 13, 14],
  [21, 22, 23],
  [31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36]
];

let newArray = [];
const maxLength = Math.max(...vidArray.map(a => a.length));

for (let i = 0; i < maxLength; i++) {
  vidArray.forEach(a => {
    if (a[i]) newArray.push(a[i]);
  });
}

console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: It works thank you! node suggested me to declare "i" so i did: for (let i = 0; i..etc

Comment: @m4tt sorry, that `let` should be there. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one potential method that uses a combination of `reduce` and `forEach`.

```js
const vidArray = [
  ["a1", "a2", "a3", "a4"],
  ["b1", "b2"],
  ["c1", "c2", "c3", "c4"],
  ["d1", "d2", "d3"]
]

const newArr = vidArray.reduce((acc, arr) => {
  arr.forEach((el, i) => {
    if (!acc[i]) acc[i] = [];
    acc[i].push(el);
  });
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(newArr);

// If you need the output as one singular array:
console.log(newArr.flat());
```